# Printing via bluetooth on android phone

Tags: android

Is there any way for printing via bluetooth on Android Phone ? Any applications ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a directory of applications that claim to allow printing from an Android device using bluetooth.

https://market.android.com/search?q=bluetooth+print&c=apps